# ReactJS - file requested from server twice

Tags: reactjs

I'm starting out with ReactJS and I'm following the simple example in the "[Gettind Started](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/getting-started.html)".

This is my HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <title>Hello React!</title>
    <script src="js/reactjs/react.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/reactjs/react-dom.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/babel" src="js/main.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="example"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

It works. But if I watch the network traffic with Fiddler, I see that `main.js` is pulled twice from the server. Is that on purpose? bug?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As soon as browser encounters following lines

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.8.23/browser.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/babel" src="js/main.js"></script>
```

browser issues http requests for both files. But since js/main.js is of 'text/babel' type for browser it won't be given to JavaScript engine to parse/execute. Rightly so, because the 'main.js' might have ES6 code which browser won't understand as it now. Once babel's browser.min.js loads and executes, it searches for script tag in DOM with type 'text/babel' and then issue XHR request to load that file. After that browser.min.js compiles the code in 'main.js' transform it into ES5 and then executes it. This is the way it works.

Since browser already has 'js/main.js' in its cache from earlier request, the XHR request issued by babel's browser.min.js for 'js/main.js' is served from the cache itself, so there won't be any additional external http request.

Comment: Is that something to do on production later on? Or is there a step to do before production?

Comment: this is how it works when you want to do compilation and transformation of ES6 code on the client/browser side. For production, it is better to use webpack. Webpack will take babel module, run your code against 'React/ES2015' presets and generate js file which will serve as a entry point for your app.